# in mongoose, how to select the fields in a array property

Tags: mongoose

in Mongoose, I have such a schema

```
var schema= mongoose.Schema({
         name:String,
         age:String
         likes: [{ type:String, price:String}]                       
});
```

As in the mongoose, the **option** in the **Model.find(conditions, [fields], [options], [callback])** gives us a choice to select the fields we need. However in my schema, there is a array property 'likes', and in the query, I only want to select only one property type rather than all of them, how can I make this query ?

Answer (score 12):

I actually found it out, just by

```
Model.findOne({ 'name': name }, 'name age likes.type', callback);
```

Comment: Make sure that you mark this answer as the correct one by clicking on the green "checkmark" under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

For `find()` you need to use `select()` chain call, something like this:

```
Model.find({ name: name }).select('name age likes.type').exec(function() {

});
```

Or

```
Model.find({ name: name }).select({ 'name': 1, 'age': 1, 'likes.type': 1 }).exec(function() {

});
```

More examples here [in Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Don't forget to use cursor for traversing over large amounts of data (it's described in the *Streaming* section of the docs).